# Laravel Scheduler not running commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.7

I have these commands scheduled in my **Kernel.php** inside **app/Console/**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command("trustpilot:send")->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command("run:status")->everyFiveMinutes();

}
```

When i run **php artisan schedule:run** i get this message :

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

It is strange because if i'm dumping **$schedule->dueEvents($this->app)** i get a list with the events **inspire** and **trustpilot:send**.

I've tried to dump the list of **dueEvents** in **/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php** but here the list is empty??

```
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    dd($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel)); <---- EMPTY?
    foreach ($this->schedule->dueEvents($this->laravel) as $event) {

        if (! $event->filtersPass($this->laravel)) {
            continue;
        }
.....
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: "*When i run php artisan schedule:run i get this message: ..."* - The answer is **don't manually run php artisan schedule:run**. Put it in a `CRON` script. Please read the schedule documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction: *"When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server."*

Comment: @TimLewis Still, the `everyMinute` commands *should* be picked up in a manual `schedule:run` call.

Comment: @ceejayoz Only if you run it at the exact second that the `everyMinute()` call corresponds to.

Comment: @TimLewis That's... not how Laravel scheduling works. It doesn't care about seconds.

Comment: @ceejayoz Doesn't it? I thought that `everyMinute()` means `XX:00`. If you log the time a scheduled command is run, it'll show seconds at 0.

Comment: @TimLewis. No. `everyMinute` gets evaluated to the cron expression `* * * * *`. Laravel assumes cron runs every minute (as it doesn't have sub-minute frequencies), so `everyMinute` means it'll get executed whenever `schedule:run` is run.

Comment: (I just double-checked by testing. I scheduled `inspire` for every minute, and ran `php artisan schedule:run` several in quick succession. It executed each time.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Hmm... Interesting. `schedule:run` must be doing something behind the scenes to determine when `everyMinute()` commands should execute. Although I'm looking at it now, and it specifically says *"This method assumes that the current number of seconds are irrelevant, and should be called once per minute."*. Very odd. Edit: Also confirmed by testing `('inspire')->everyMinute()`, works.

Comment: @TimLewis.. I'm sorry to say.. ceejayoz has right. 

I only run the command manually for testing purpose.

Comment: No apology necessary :) I hadn't seen this use case before; there's been lots of other questions about this issue ("No scheduled commands ..."), but most of them didn't have `everyMinute()`, so when they were running it manually, it actually wasn't the correct time (like `everyFiveMinutes()` for example). Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

In boot command of my application i ran this:

```
Artisan::call('....');
```

It overrides the old schedueler instance and thats why the dueEvent list was empty.

I removed the line and then i works :)